# Работа с функцией time(): вычитание времени

Tags: php, функции

Здравствуйте! Как вообще работать с функцией. `time()` как вычитать время и.т.д.?

Comment: удобнее [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Возвращает текущее время, измеренное в секундах с начала 1970-го года.

У вас, скажем, есть переменная `$startTime = time();` → потом идет код, который занимает какое-то время → потом `$endTime = time();`. Теперь, чтобы узнать, сколько времени заняло выполнение вашего скрипта, нужно от `$endTime` отнять `$startTime` — получите количество секунд. Надеюсь, пересчитать секунды в другие единицы измерения вы сможете?

Еще есть такая замечательная штука — [мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) на `php.net` и там есть [примеры использования](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php#102017)

Comment: Только там ещё подводные камни есть, например количество дней в месяце.

Comment: а вот как сделать,например есть кнопка, при нажатии установить время например time()+3600;  пока время не истечет выводить сколько осталось, а иначе выводить кнопку !) с.з